# require external directory with php

Tags: php, composer-php, require

I am trying to include a library with composer. To do this I need to require vendor/autoload.php

```
    require '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

The issue is this file directory is outside of the web root and I would like to keep it that way. So when I try this bit of code it spits out

```
       Warning: require(/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/sandbox5678/StreamIt/cool.php on line 9

       Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/sandbox5678/StreamIt/cool.php on line 9
```

is there a way to have it go to an external directory??

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't care if the file is inside the document root or not. Simply use the correct path to it.

If the vendor folder is one level up from the file containing the `require`, then do:

```
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php'.
```

`__DIR__` = returns the full path to the folder where the PHP-file is in.
`/..` = Go up one level from the current path.
`/../..` = Go up two levels from the current path and so on...

Comment: it just spits out this error   Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/sandbox5678/StreamIt/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/sandbox5678/StreamIt/index.php on line 6

Comment: @KidCoder - That's an example how it would look like if the vendor folder was one level up from the file you're writing this in. Clearly, your vendor folder is somewhere else, so just adjust the path... It's quite impossible for me to know the correct path on your system...

Comment: No if you look at it it clearly is still looking in the same directory it is just adding /.. to the path I tried it with the right number of /.. s it did the same thing